# Firebase Cloud Functions won't delete Firestore document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to delete a "draft" document on the creation of a "post" document with the same key. However, though the trigger and function execution is successful, the document just won't delete. Security rules for read, write, update, delete are all allowed. Using typescript.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()

export const newPost = functions.firestore
.document('users/{uid}/posts/{postID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid
    const postID = context.params.postID
    let ref = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('drafts').doc(postID)
    return ref.delete()
})
```

Comment: Since we can't see that the values of the variables are exactly what you need to delete the document, there's not much we can do.  I suggest editing the question to add some logging to show the values of all the variables, and show a screenshot of the document that clearly shows that the variables match the document to delete.

Comment: It actually randomly works now. I think the security rules for allow delete didn't propagate properly.

Comment: Oh and btw your videos on Cloud Functions on the Firebase channel are brilliant. Thanks @DougStevenson!

Comment: Backend code running in cloud functions is not affected by security rules at all actually.

Comment: If you changed anything, please, consider adding an answer to confirm the change, if not, to let the Community knows that you don't need more assistance, if it's working.